# Laravel: Cannot reindex collection's array in eager loading after using unset()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have following code:

```
// User.php
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Group::class,
        'group_user',
        'user_id',
        'group_id',
        'id'
    );
}


// Group.php
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        User::class,
        'group_class',
        'group_id',
        'user_id',
        'id'
    );
}
```

And in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $me = App\User::first();

    $group = App\Group::with('users')->first();

    foreach ($group->users as $user_index => $user) {

        // Show all users (a.k.a members) of this group, except myself
        if ($user->id == $me->id) {
            unset($group->users[$user_index]);
        }
    }

    return $group;
}):
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABC Group",
    "users": { // This should be array right?
        "1": { // This should be start with 0
            "id": 2,
            "name": "...",
            "email": "...",
        },
        "2": { // This should be 1
            "id": 3,
            "name": "...",
            "email": "...",
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

- #1 Put `values()` in the end of `foreach` loop, like:

  ```
      foreach ($group->users as $user_index => $user) {

           // Show all users (a.k.a members) of this group, except myself
           if ($user->id == $me->id) {
                unset($group->users[$user_index]);
           }

           $group->users->values(); // Not working
      }
  ```
- #2 Put `values()` after the `foreach` loop, like:

  ```
      Route::get('/test', function () {
           $me = App\User::first();

           $group = App\Group::with('users')->first();

           foreach ($group->users as $user_index => $user) {
                // Show all users (a.k.a members) of this group, except myself
                if ($user->id == $me->id) {
                     unset($group->users[$user_index]);
                }
           }

           $group->users->values(); // Still not working

           return $group;
      }):
  ```

Expected result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ABC Group",
    "users": [ // Array
        { // index 0
            "id": 2,
            "name": "...",
            "email": "...",
        },
        { // index 1
            "id": 3,
            "name": "...",
            "email": "...",
        }
    ]
}
```

> Q: How to reindex collection array in eager loading after using `unset()`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few things to unpack here that might help you.

First, your query returns a Laravel [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) of users attached to the single model `Group`.  Laravel has a bit of magic in the background that allows for array notation as well, but probably easiest to think about this as a collection for your purposes.  In some cases, you can translate this to an array using Laravel's `toArray()` method, something like:

```
$userArray = $group->users->toArray();
```

For dropping an index, or in this case a `user` from the `Group`'s users, take a look at the [forget](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-forget)() method, which works on the `collection` object.

However, I think you may wish to come at this from the reverse...  Pull the unwanted index(es) in a single query, rather than having to loop through the collection after the fact.   Something like this may be of value to you:

```
$me = App\User::first();

$group = App\Group::with(['users'  => function($query) use($me){
        $query->where('users.id', '!=', $me->id);
    }])->first();
```

This query will remove the unwanted user from the collection *right out of the database, eliminating the need for additional code*, which is what I think you were after.

HTH.