# Laravel reindex collection for pagnation after having used forget on elements in collection

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a collection I get by:

```
$clinics = Clinic::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(30)->withQueryString();
```

Assume this has up to 5000 items.

Now I need to sort out clinics that are move than 20km away from an address that a user inputs, in a `foreach($clinics as $key => $clinic)` loop.

I then calculate if it is within 20 km, and if the clinic is more than 20km away, i use `$clinics->forget($key);`.

Assume now the collection has maybe 100 items.

So far so good (if not for pagination).

But now when I go to the page with the pagination, most of the pages are blank, and the pagination says that there are 200 pages, even though there is only 100 items, and 30 per page would result in 4 pages.

I believe this is because the keys in the collection is forgotten, but the pagination still assumes the entire collection.

**How do I reindex a collection in laravel, and still have the pagination available?**

I could do a scopeGetDistance, but how would I in the query do a "take this item, and leave this item out" based on a calculation?

I have looked into this:

- [Update/Recalculate pagination after dropping some items from collection](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/updaterecalculate-pagination-after-dropping-some-items-from-collection) but this isn't really clearly stated how this would be implemented, or at least i cant see how.
- [Laravel: Cannot reindex collection's array in eager loading after using unset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66674260/laravel-cannot-reindex-collections-array-in-eager-loading-after-using-unset) - but this does not take into account the pagination as far as I can tell.

UPDATE:

The following code is in scope:

```
public function scopeCloseTo($query, $lat, $long)
{
    return $query->whereRaw("
       ST_Distance_Sphere(
            point(long, lat),
            point(?, ?)
        ) * .000621371192 < 20
    ", [
        $long,
        $lat,
    ]);
}
```

This returns error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'long, lat), point(?, ?) ) * .000621371192 < 20 ' at line 3 (SQL: select count(*)
 as aggregate from `clinics` where ST_Distance_Sphere( point(long, lat), point(11.816458, 55.451428) )
 * .000621371192 < 20 and `clinic_type_id` = 1)
```

Comment: May I know your logic to calculate distance? Can we move it inside query?

Comment: @Bhushan the logic is that on each clinic there is a lat and long variable in database, and on the address which is entered I lookup the lat and long on that address, and then based on a rewrite of pythagoras theorem I can calculate the distance between the address and a clinic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are calculating distance based on latitude and longitude you can directly get it calculated in mysql using ST_Distance_Sphere function. you can know more about this function in this blog([ST_Distance_Sphere Example](https://tighten.com/blog/a-mysql-distance-function-you-should-know-about/)).

In your query you are fetching all clinics after that you are checking whether distance is more than 20Km or not and if not then you are deleting it from pagination object and so it was creating an issue. So do that validation directly in mysql query so pagination object will always give required data. Below is an eloquent query, that will only returns the clinics which are more than 20Km away from user.

```
Clinic::orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->whereRaw(ST_Distance_Sphere(point('clinic_longitude', clinic_latitude), point($user_longitude, $user_latitude)) > 20000
    ->paginate(30)
    ->withQueryString();
```